# Zoom recording webhook

Tags: python, fastapi, zoom-sdk

I've make the webhook endpoint for zoom. I can receive the meeting webhook but I can't receive the recording webhook

```
@router.post('/webhook')
async def webhook(request: Request):
    headers = dict(request.headers)
    body = await request.json()
    print(headers)
    print(body)

    if 'payload' in body and 'plainToken' in body['payload']:
        secret_token = ZOOM_SECRET_TOKEN.encode("utf-8")
        plaintoken = body['payload']['plainToken']
        mess = plaintoken.encode("utf-8")
        has = hmac.new(secret_token, mess, hashlib.sha256).digest()
        hexmessage = has.hex()

        response = {
            'message': {
                'plainToken': plaintoken,
                'encryptedToken': hexmessage
            }
        }
        print(response['message'])
        return response['message']
    else:
        return {'error': 'Invalid payload'}
```

There something wrong with my code or something else?

Comment: If you are receiving the [Meeting webhook](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/api/rest/reference/zoom-api/events/#operation/meeting.started), you should have the code setup correctly. I would double check you have the Cloud Recording webhooks enabled in your app's build flow, and you are [triggering the webhook (actually starting Cloud Recording in the meeting)](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/api/rest/reference/zoom-api/events/#operation/recording.completed).